# Java, continuing after Try-Catch

Tags: java, try-catch

When I run the program 100 is divided by the numbers, but once it reaches 0 a message appears telling to user that 100 cannot be divided by 0.

How do I get the program to continue after the error and divide 100 with the rest of the numbers.

This is my current code:

```
public class testing {
    int[] table;
    int number;

    public testing(int number) {
        this.number = number;
        table = new int[number];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int[] numbers = { 2, 3, 0, 4, 5 };
            testing division;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                division = new testing(100 / numbers[i]);
                System.out.println("Answer is " + division.number);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("A number cannot be divided by 0");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, please, please, use tools that provide standard indentation, any good IDE will do it.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply make the try / catch on a finer grained scale -- put it *inside* the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    try {
        division = new testing(100 / numbers[i]);
        System.out.println("Answer is " + division.number);
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) { // avoid catching with the overly broad Exception 
        System.out.println("A number cannot be divided by 0");
    }
}
```

I'd try to make my exceptions more specific and avoid catching using the overly broad Exception class, here using ArithmeticException.

But even more importantly, I'd get rid of the try catch entirely and simply test for 0 avoiding the exception altogether.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] == 0) {
        System.out.println("A number cannot be divided by 0");
    } else {
        division = new testing(100 / numbers[i]);
        System.out.println("Answer is " + division.number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if exception occurs there is no way to go back ,but we can handle the exception and go with next iteration or just add below if condition before division:

```
**if(numbers[i] != 0){**
division = new testing(100/numbers[i]);
```

or put try catch inside for loop.

Comment: "if exception occurs there is no way to go back" -- this is absolutely correct. if exception occurs we can only handle the exception and program can move ahead , Its a generic statement in case of excpetion . in others example they are handing exception inside for loop it mean if exception is occurring they are handling that exception and moving ahead with next iteration. in that way if there are many zero elements array then exceptions will be thrown each time.

Comment: modified the answer in different way

Comment: Thank you. Vote swapped: down-vote removed, up-vote given.

Answer (score 1):

Put try-catch within the for:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   try{
     division = new testing(100/numbers[i]);
     System.out.println("Answer is " + division.number);
   } catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("A number cannot be divided by 0");
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update code: Added one more try catch in your code:

```
public class testing {

  int[] table;
  int number;

  public testing(int number) {
    this.number = number;
    table = new int[number];
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = { 2, 3, 0, 4, 5 };
    testing division;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      try {
        division = new testing(100 / numbers[i]);
        System.out.println("Answer is " + division.number);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("A number cannot be divided by 0");
      }
    }
  }
}
```